# rewriting rich client application from "iText 5" to "iText 8" throws a PdfException

Tags: itext

I'm updating my rich client application from iText5 to iText8. The application was working flawlessly in iText5. It generates PDF files dynamically from data from all kind of sources.

The first call to generate a PDF works perfectly on the updated app on iText8. But then I get the following exception on all followup calls:

com.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:191)
...

The exception says, on the second call some resources from the first call are referenced.
The application is really complex and thus hard to trace what is referenced.

Is there a way to evaluate, which element is the reason for this exception?

Thanks, Claus

Comment: You can either use a debugger, set a break point for the exception, debug until the right exception is thrown, and analyze the local variables of the call stack. Or you can piecewise inactivate the PDF creation code until you have isolated the problem content.